# IE image is displayed in localhost but not online(BHO)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am creating a BHO for internet explorer in C#, and I am unable to insert an image.
The image is inserted correctly if I save the webpage(facebook.com/myprofile) to localhost and open it in IE, but not online. When I compile the project the image is added to a directory near the currently executing assembly. If I use IE HTML debugger(F12) and check for  and follow the src, it is correct, and if I open it in a new tab, the images is displayed. why is this happening? Can it be some sort of permission problem regarding IE or BHO settings? Thx in advance..

Comment: Could you please describe exactly how you add the image to the page, and what syntax do you use. Are you using document.createElement and appentChild or some other method? What element exactly do you insert (specifically, what is the src attribute)? Can you copy the OuterHTML (from the F12 tool)?

Comment: Hi Uri... I specified the to be inserted elements in a string, then used d1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", insertDiv);, where d1 is the element after which i want the div and the img inside it inserted, insertDiv being the string I described

Comment: This method is working for me, both when executing from JavaScript, or from a C++ BHO. Could be a problem with the string that you insert is wrong. If you still want to solve this issue, let me know the string you insert, as well as the result OuterHTML from the F12 utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I'm still not sure why IE will not display the  tag correctly when inserting it from BHO but I got round through this by simulating an img tag with a div and giving it a background image with CSS, all inserted by BHO through C# code